# OTRS - configure smtp to add a custom sendgrid header?

Tags: smtp, sendmail, email, otrs, sendgrid

I'd like to be able to configure OTRS ticket system to send email through sendgrid but I also want to add some configuration parameters through the X-SMTPAPI sendgrid header.

There's no obvious config setting I can see that would allow me to add a header to sent email through smtp in OTRS.

Any idea how I could do this?

*A couple of notes of importance:*

- The server itself uses qmail, but I can't configure the entire local server to go through sendgrid because it runs some other services that shouldn't go through sendgrid
- I'd like to avoid as much as possible changing the OTRS source files if possible because a) i don't know perl that well and b) that's asking for trouble

Comment: Can I ask why you use sendgrid? What's the benefit? Also, would you send to sendgrid using SMTP? Please explain, I can probably put you in the right direction for adding headers.

Comment: @Mike. For stats & for signing. Need to add headers to place in a category and also to enable signing of emails. And yes, SMTP seems the way to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a working sendmail installation, you can add the `SMART_HOST` parameter to relay all mail to sendgrid.

See this [SendGrid documentation for details](http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/get-started/integrate/examples/sendmail/).